# User ID Module- hashing email address

Tags: php, userid, prebid.js, user-identification

All media websites can now share the **hashed** email addresses of their users through different prebid user modules. (https://docs.prebid.org/dev-docs/modules/userId.html)
Normally, you can use the php hash function to hash all the emails, before implementing the right module and send all the hashes. Any ideas on how this function can be implemented?

I found this script https://gist.github.com/ehedaya/288c7280ee76b436cceec15941e4093a but I don't see where it should be added.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Generally the integration of Prebid.js User ID modules with hashed emails  involves 3 steps:

1. Use hash function in your server side languages to get hashed email value
2. Pass that value to your front-end for Prebid.js, perhaps via cookies or hidden element on HTML
3. In your front-end JS, read values from step 2, and pass it to Prebid.js UserID modules

Now back to your questions:

> I found this script https://gist.github.com/ehedaya/288c7280ee76b436cceec15941e4093a but I don't see where it should be added.

This only covers the steps 1. You need to take the hashed email and follow steps 2 & 3 to make User ID modules work.